# Recommended Project Structure for Docker

Tags: go, docker

I'm working on a Go project that has the following structure (schematic):

```
./lib1
./prog1
    ./...
./prog2
    ./...
```

Where:

- lib1 is a library
- prog1 and prog2 are executables (both depend on lib1)

**In a nutshell:** How do I create Dockerfiles for prog1 and prog2?

---

I tried several approaches, all to no avail:

### Creating a Dockerfile in prog1/

Failed because docker cannot `ADD ../lib1` to the container since it is out of the context (see http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add).

### Creating a Dockerfile in the root directory

Ignoring the fact that I actually need two Dockerfiles (for prog1, and for prog2), I tried placing the Dockerfile in the root directory of the project.

However, the docker image I need to use (golang:1.4.1-onbuild) fails to find any Go files (since they are in ./prog1, and not in the root):

```
+ exec go install -v
can't load package: package app: no buildable Go source files in /go/src/app
```

**What is the recommended project structure for the golang:1.4.1-onbuild image?**

---

**Edit:** Better asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209202/dockerizing-gos-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

Most pull the files in via their VCS or just `go get` instead of using `ADD`.  You add the the source tree in the same way regardless of what tool your building, since you need the structure of `$GOPATH` to be the same for each.

Note, you can also name your docker file via `docker build -f`, so if you want to use `ADD`, you can have multiple DOCKERFILEs in your root directory.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a basic assumption Go makes (pulling the source from VCS). Is it intentionally hard to use proprietary code? Ultimately I'm deploying to a cloud service that might not have access to my company's VCS...

Comment: @benzaita: Most people keep code in a VCS, proprietary or not. Regardless, it only a convenience. You can generate your GOPATH any way you want -- tar it up and pull it with http if it suits you.

Comment: You usually deploy the built image. then there is no need for VCS anymore, as you did that when building the image. Also: why don't you use the binaries (prog1 and 2) for deployment?